# `vscode debug angular can't hit breakpoint: breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular8

I refered the method in this article:[How To Debug An Angular Application In Chrome](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-debug-an-angular-application-in-chrome/)
 to debug the angular app in vscode with `Debugger for Chrome`, but cannot hit the breakpoint: `breakpoint set but not yet bound`.

vscode version: 1.41.0
angular version: 8.2.14
`Debug for chrome` version: 4.12.6

My project struct is:

```
|--.vscode
|      |--lanuch.json
|--dist
|    |--ng-app
|          |--index.html
|          |--...
|          
|--projects
|     |--ng-app
|     |    |--e2e
|     |    |--src
|     |
|     |--ng-demo
|          |--e2e
|          |--src 
|     
|--angular.json
|--tsconfig.json
|--package.json
```

I want to debug `ng-app`, the launch.json file content:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know where's wrong, and how to solve it. I searched on google, but not get an appropriate answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the webRoot, it need to point to the application:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/myapp/src",
```